# Total number of documents in pysolr

Tags: python-2.7, solr, pysolr

How can I get the total number of documents matching the given query. I have use the query below:

```
result = solr.search('ad_id : 20')
print(len(result))
```

Since the default returning value is '10', the output is only 10, but the count is 4000. How can I get the total number of counts?

Answer (score 4):

The [results object from pysolr has a `hits` property that contains the total number of hits](https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr/blob/master/pysolr.py#L271), regardless of how many documents being returned. This is named `numFound` in the raw response from Solr.

Your solution isn't really suitable for anything with a larger dataset, since it requires you to retrieve *all* the documents, even if you don't need them or want to show their content.

Answer (score 4):

The count is stored in numFound variable. Use the code below:

```
result = solr.search('ad_id : 20')
print(result.raw_response['response']['numFound'])
```

Comment: How does this differ from the 'hits' property available on the result? There is no need to use the raw response.

Answer (score 2):

As @MatsLindh mentioned -

```
result = solr.search('ad_id : 20')
print(result.hits)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the total number of items that satisfy your query, here is my Python3 code (using the pysolr module):

```
    collection='bookindex'  # or whatever your collection is called
    solr_url = f"http://{SOLR_HOST}/solr/{collection}"
    solr = pysolr.Solr(url=solr_url, timeout=120, always_commit=True)
    result = solr.search("*:*", rows=0);
    return result.hits
```

This queries for all documents ("*:*") -- 315913 in my case -- but you can narrow that to suit your requirements.  For example, if I want to know how many of my book entries have title:pandas I can search("title:pandas", rows=0) and get 41 as the number that have pandas in the title.  By setting rows=0 you're letting Solr know that it need not format *any* results for you but you just return the meta information, and thus much more efficient than setting a high limit on rows.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer:

Added `rows=1000000` at the end of the query.

`result = solr.search('ad_id : 20', rows=1000000)`

But if the rows are greater than this the number should be changed in the query. This might be a bad solution but works.
If anyone has a better solution please do reply.